# JS/Jquery get clicked id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the id from an clicked a element using jquery.

For example a user clicks on a `<a></a>` element I want the ID to store inside a variable. I know how to manage this using `<select></select>` elements but got no clue how to manage this using a simple menu containing a links.

Preview:

[image: preview]

Source code:

```
<div class="list-group no-border mb-5">
    <a id="background" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-bucket"></i> Profile Background</a>
    <a id="boxes" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-cube"></i> Profile Boxes</a>
    <a id="fonts" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-font"></i> Profile Fonts</a>
    <a id="highlights" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-stack-empty"></i> Profile Highlights</a>
    <a id="content" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-markup"></i> Profile Content</a>
    <a id="media" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-video-camera2"></i> Profile Media</a>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways that you could resolve the ID of which element was clicked since you are using jQuery. You'll just need to ensure that you have a variable defined in the proper scope (i.e. outside of your click event) :

```
<script>
    // Example variable
    var clickedId;
    // jQuery code here
</script>
```

Then define a click event handler to pick up any click events and set your variable using either `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`, which will both return the ID attribute of the element clicked (i.e. `this`) :

```
<script>
    // Example variable
    var clickedId;
    $(function(){
         // When any link is clicked
         $('a').click(function(){
              // Set your variable
              clickedId = this.id; // or clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
         });
    });
</script>
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
// Example variable
var clickedId;
$(function(){
   // When any link is clicked
   $('a').click(function(){
         // Set your variable
         clickedId = this.id; // or clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
         console.log(clickedId + ' was stored in clickedId');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group no-border mb-5">
    <a id="background" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-bucket"></i> Profile Background</a>
    <br />
    <a id="boxes" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-cube"></i> Profile Boxes</a>
  <br />
    <a id="fonts" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-font"></i> Profile Fonts</a>
  <br />
    <a id="highlights" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-stack-empty"></i> Profile Highlights</a>
  <br />
    <a id="content" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-markup"></i> Profile Content</a>
  <br />
    <a id="media" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-video-camera2"></i> Profile Media</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var theID;
$('a').click(function(){
    theID = this.id;
})
```

```js
var theID;
$('a').click(function(){
  theID = this.id;
  console.log(theID);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group no-border mb-5">
    <a id="background" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-bucket"></i> Profile Background</a>
    <a id="boxes" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-cube"></i> Profile Boxes</a>
    <a id="fonts" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-font"></i> Profile Fonts</a>
    <a id="highlights" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-stack-empty"></i> Profile Highlights</a>
    <a id="content" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-markup"></i> Profile Content</a>
    <a id="media" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-video-camera2"></i> Profile Media</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id;    
$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    // Then do something with your id..
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the id of currently clicked element(tag `a`)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(evt){
      console.log(evt.target.id);             
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group no-border mb-5">
    <a id="background" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-bucket"></i> Profile Background</a>
    <a id="boxes" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-cube"></i> Profile Boxes</a>
    <a id="fonts" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-font"></i> Profile Fonts</a>
    <a id="highlights" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-stack-empty"></i> Profile Highlights</a>
    <a id="content" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-markup"></i> Profile Content</a>
    <a id="media" class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-video-camera2"></i> Profile Media</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has the .click() event for when the user clicks on something. http://api.jquery.com/click/

And the .attr() method for getting an attribute like id. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

For example:

```
var clicked_id
$(a).click(function() {
  clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```